# Configuring UART pins on Beaglebone Black for CAN Interface

Tags: uart, can, linux, beaglebone-black

I have been using a [CAN/RS485 Cape](https://www.waveshare.com/rs485-can-cape.htm) for prototyping CAN control of a motor. I am now in the process of bringing up some custom hardware. I have a [CAN Transceiver SN65HVD230D](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd230.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1601582160789) on this custom cape that is connected to pins 31 and 32 on P8 - UART5 TX/RX.

I tried simply configuring the pinmux using `config-pin` however I got two errors:

```
user@beaglebone:/lib/firmware$ sudo config-pin P8.31 can
P8_31 pinmux file not found!
Invalid mode: can
```

Is it necessary to create a device tree overlay as [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195416/beaglebone-black-can-bus-setup) suggests?

Is it even possible to use these pins for CAN or is CAN only available through DCAN0/1_RX/TX pins?

Comment: I am trying to bring up a cape designed by a contractor

Comment: My unconfirmed suspicion would be that this isn't going to easily work, maybe ask them what they were thinking?  You could probably white-wire the cape to get signals from different connector pins.

Comment: That said you seem to have a bunch of overlapping issues - eg, you have now one but *two* error messages showing, and the runtime config vs device tree points to the fact that the beaglebone has been around long enough to have multiple conflicting conventions for how software manages hardware; you'll need the one appropriate to your Linux, or a Linux appropriate to the method you want to use.

Comment: Gotcha. That's a pretty simple fix. I have been able to config pins P9.24 and P9.26 properly interestingly enough. I'm not sure why pinmuxing isn't working for P8.31/32.

Comment: Can you help clarify what the BBB MCU is doing in this case? It looks like it has two DCAN interfaces - is it implementing the "data-link" layer of the OSI model?  With SN65HVD as the physical layer?